# Bootstrap row error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 cols in my Bootstrap grid, there are multiple rows each box is filled with data from my DB.

All is fine until it gets to `row 13` then I only get one box not 3, then it goes back to 3 on the next line until row 18 where I get 2 on a line.. the last 5 rows are fine.

I've tried fixing the height of the container the rows, I've tried tables with fixed height nothing seem to work.

Code is straight forward:

```
    <div class="container" >
       <div class="row" >
         <div class="col-md-4" >
           Content from database
```

So it looks like this:

```
    row 10 =  box  box  box
    row 11 =  box  box  box
    row 12 =  box  box  box
    row 13 =            box
    row 14 =  box  box  box
    row 15 =  box  box  box
    row 16 =  box  box  box
    row 17 =  box  box  box
    row 18 =       box  box
    row 19 =  box  box  box
```

Comment: share some code with us please.

Comment: And a JSFiddle / Bootply as well (http://jsfiddle.net / http://bootply.com)

Comment: can you please also share some data from database specifiacaly data for row 13.

Comment: The row 13 data (this is the only record that shows on that line)
ID: 170, 
title: New Rock Goth Boots - 1011-S1, 
Desription:  New Rock Goth Boots - 1011-S1 Steel Tower Black Hole, 
sizes: EU36 (UK3)-EU37 (UK4)-EU38 (UK5)-EU39 (UK5.5)-EU40 (UK6)-EU41 (UK7)-EU42 (UK8)-EU43 (UK9)-EU44 (UK9.5)-EU45 (UK10)-EU46 (UK11)-EU47 (UK12), 
Price: 144.95, 
Sml Image: M1011-S1-new-rock-goth-boot.jpg, 
Lrg Image: M1011-S1-new-rock-goth-boot_t.jpg, 
Keywords: New Rock Goth Boots - 1011-S1,
Category: 2, 
Sub Category: 10

Comment: Problem solved.. by adding <div class="clearfix"></div> at the end of each row

Answer (score 0):

To fix this bug you should set a fixed height to all columns:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="height:150px">
```